# Getter not returning the right values

Tags: angular

I am trying to sum up all of my sub totals and return a grand total but I get wild values and I used to get the error: Expression has changed after it was checked.

When I use

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

it suppresses the expression has changed error but I still get wild values for the grand total.

This is in my component:

```
totals : number[ ] = [ ];

get grandTotal() {

    let i;
    let sub_total = 0;
    let grand_total = 0;
if  (this.isSubmitted == true){
    sub_total = this.product_price * this.quantity;

    if (typeof this.product_price  === "undefined") {
        return 0;
    } else {
        this.totals.push(sub_total);
        for (i = 0; i < this.totals.length; i++) {
            grand_total += this.totals[i];
this.isSubmitted = false;
        }
        return grand_total;
    }
}
}
```

This is in my HTML;

```
<div>Grand Total {{ grandTotal }}</div>
```

Comment: Every time the component gets rendered `this.totals.push(sub_total);` is executed. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Caramiriel. I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: how do you save products to the list, and where (firebase, sql, json, xml)

Comment: I set issubmitted to true in my onSubmit function and executed  if (this.isSubmited == true) in my getter but it didn't remedy the problem.

Comment: I edited my question to show the new condition.

Comment: @Tomasz Vizaint I save products in an onSubmit function which gets the products from a form. The products in the form were displayed using firebase.

Comment: The first submission works but then after that the grand total updates before the form is submitted. The isSubmitted variable must have been changed to true even though the form only submitted once. How can I prevent the isSubmitted variable from remaining true?

Comment: I was able to fix this by setting  this.isSubmitted = false; in my getter.

Comment: Thanks, Caramiriel! I wouldn't have been able to solve the problem without your tip.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - what I understand you want something like this.
[image: Order]

A few weeks ago I finished a project where is the situation you want to achieve.
I will try to explain how it works on this site, the operation of adding products to a list, and calculate the sum of the entire order.

The customer chooses a product, selects the quantity and adds to an order.
[image: product]

If the order is new a new order document is created, and to this document is added new collection with products, the client make select another product and add this to the same order

And since it is saved in a firebase document when adding product to the list it also adds some more parameters. Like this.

[image]

and this data collect for checkout as in the first image.
I get this list of products. This in OrderService

```
getProdListInOrder(user, orderid) {
    return this.db.collection('users').doc(user).collection('ordersout')
      .doc(orderid).collection('products').snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(action => action.map(as => {
          const id = as.payload.doc.id;
          const data = as.payload.doc.data() as OrderProdData;
          return { id, ...data };
        }))
      );
  }
```

In checkOut component using this method i show a client all information about order;
In this method

```
getProdInOrder() {
    this.osrv.getProdListFromOrder(this.USERID, this.PEDIID).subscribe(prolist => {
      this.listaPR = prolist;
      this.LISTAPROD.emit(prolist);
      this.listaprice = [];
      //extract only totalprice to the list
      this.listaPR.forEach(tp => {
        this.listaprice.push(tp.totalprice);
      });
      this.TotalTicket = this.listaprice.reduce((ac, cur) => ac + cur, 0);
      this.TOTALPRICE.emit(this.TotalTicket);
    });
  }
```

in this method I extract only total prices and added to "list price" and with function reduces i sum all order.
You can also calculate sum of prices without extracting total price.

```
this.TotalTicket = this.listaPR.map(t => t.totalprice).reduce((ac, cur) => ac + cur, 0);
```

if you have more questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz Vizaint but I found a simpler solution.

Comment: Can you give me the link, maybe I improve my app

Comment: The simpler solution is the one I published. There is no link. I edited my post to show the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by setting isSubmitted to true in my onSubmit function and setting it to false at the end of my getter. I have edited my post to show this.